# Can't get this text over to the left

Tags: html, css, positioning, css-float, styling

[image]

I'm trying to get the "about 15 hours ago" text to the left, but can't seem to get it done. float left doesn't seem to work, and I can't decrease the margin left because then the "3 minutes ago" text will collide with the image.

Here's the html(sorry for the big mess):

```
<div class="comment_column_narrow">
    <div id="comment_title_39" class="comment_title">
        Do you like this song?

        <a href="/comment_titles/39" class="comment_title_delete" data-method="delete" data-remote="true" rel="nofollow">x</a>
    </div>


    <div class="comment_content">
          <a href="/profiles/45" class="comment_image"><img alt="Justin meltzer" src="/system/photos/45/tiny/Justin Meltzer.jpeg?1302075215"></a>
          <div class="textual_comment_content">
              <div class="comment_text">
                 <span class="name_link">
                     <a href="/profiles/45" class="normal">Justin Meltzer</a>
                 </span>
             Ok so this is what I think about this song: You need to switch back to your roots. You started as a rapper, and you need to remain a rapper. I respect you for your initiative to improve your flexibility but please stick to your roots. That's what makes you truly great.
              </div>
               <span class="comment_footer">
             <ul>
            <li class="list_style">about 15 hours ago.</li>
         </ul>
           <span>
      </span></span></div></div></div>
```

And here's the corresponding CSS:

```
.comment_column_narrow {
    float: left;
    width: 295px;
    margin-right: 5px;
}

.comment_content{
    clear:both;
    padding: 10px 5px;
    border-top:2px solid #E2E2E2;
    border-right:3px solid #E2E2E2;
}

.comment_text{
    line-height: 120%;
}

.comment_image{
    float:left;
    margin-right: 10px;
}

.comment_footer{

}

.comment_footer ul{
   margin-top: 5px;
}

.comment_footer ul li{
    font-size: 10px;
    color:gray;
    float:left;
    margin-right:25px;
}

.list_style{
    list-style:none;
}

.name_link{
     margin-left:-3px;
}
```

Comment: Chromium 10 and Firefox 4, on Ubuntu 10.10, seems to display as you require: [JS Fiddle demo of posted code](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Yxepd/). Which browser/platform are you using?

Comment: Could you post the HTML for the Feedback/3 minutes ago part ... Maybe there's something different between the two, since it doesn't look like this is dynamic.  Furthermore, I don't know why you are using a span for the comment_footer with a nested ul instead of just using a div and removing the ul/li.

Comment: @Scott, the html for the feed/3 minutes ago is exactly the same.

Comment: @Scott, could you please provide an example of how you would so without the span and ul? Maybe that would do it...

Comment: @Justin - sorry, had to leave work.  Glad to see my suggestion was right on track though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

this:

```
<div class="comment_text">
    <span class="name_link">
        <a href="/profiles/45" class="normal">Justin Meltzer</a>
    </span>
    Ok so this is what I think about this song: You need to switch back to your roots. You started as a rapper, and you need to remain a rapper. I respect you for your initiative to improve your flexibility but please stick to your roots. That's what makes you truly great.
</div>
<span class="comment_footer">
    <ul>
        <li class="list_style">about 15 hours ago.</li>
    </ul>
</span>
```

Move the comment_footer span INSIDE the comment_text span, so that it wraps around the image as you desire. Then remove the `<ul>` and `<li>` as they are just getting in your way. You end up with:

```
<div class="comment_text">
    <span class="name_link">
        <a href="/profiles/45" class="normal">Justin Meltzer</a>
    </span>
    Ok so this is what I think about this song: You need to switch back to your roots. You started as a rapper, and you need to remain a rapper. I respect you for your initiative to improve your flexibility but please stick to your roots. That's what makes you truly great.
    <span class="comment_footer">about 15 hours ago.</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing to the comment section to this:

```
    <div class="comment_content">
        <a href="/profiles/45" class="comment_image"><img alt="Justin meltzer" src="/system/photos/45/tiny/Justin Meltzer.jpeg?1302075215"></a>
        <div class="textual_comment_content">
            <div class="comment_text">
                <a href="/profiles/45" class="normal name_link">Justin Meltzer</a>
                Ok so this is what I think about this song: You need to switch back to your roots. You started as a rapper, and you need to remain a rapper. I respect you for your initiative to improve your flexibility but please stick to your roots. That's what makes you truly great.
            </div>
            <div class="comment_footer">
                about 15 hours ago.
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```